# How to omit empty strings in output

Tags: powershell

I'm splitting a csv on the comma and taking the 6th cell:

```
Get-Content .\BSEG_EXPORT.csv | foreach { $_.Split(",")[6] }
```

However, this returns a lot of empty strings (no match on the current line):

```
""
""
"something" 
""
""
```

How can I ommit the `""` in my output? So:

```
"something"
```

I tried

```
Get-Content .\BSEG_EXPORT.csv | foreach { $a = $_.Split(",")[6] } | Where { $a -ne "" }
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
Get-Content .\BSEG_EXPORT.csv | foreach { 
  $cell = $_.Split(",")[6] 
  if ($cell -ne '""' ) { write-output $cell }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but trying this on the commandline (`Get-Content .\BSEG_EXPORT.csv | foreach { $cell = $_.Split(",")[6] if ($cell -ne "") { Write-Host $cell } }`) gives me an error: `Unexpected token if`. I can probably put it in a .ps1 and it'll work, but how do I formet this for the command line?

Comment: add a semi colon between the `$cell` assignment and the `if` if you're doing it all on one line: `$cell = $_.Split(",")[6] ; if ($cell ...) {... }`

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
Get-Content .\BSEG_EXPORT.csv | foreach { $_.Split(",")[6] -ne '""'}
```